# Rubyの複数バージョンのGemの切り替え方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

扱いたいRubyのバージョンが古く、
個別でGemをインストールしています。
あるGemの依存関係のGemがインストールされる際に
既存のGemが重複することがあります。
重複したGemを両方残しつつ切り替えを
行いたいです。ご教授お願いします。

Comment: bundler は利用していますか? : https://bundler.io/

Answer (score 0):

インストール済みの複数のバージョンのGemの切り替えであれば、
`gem( gem_name, *version_requirements ) -> bool` です。

例えば、通常だと最新バージョンが呼ばれますが

```
require "csv"

p CSV::VERSION #=> "3.1.9"
```

require の前にバージョン指定すると

```
require "rubygems"
gem "csv", "3.1.7"
require "csv"

p CSV::VERSION #=> "3.1.7"
```

となります。